# How do I exclude a single row from groupby().transform() in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My intended goal was to perform a simple `groupby`, then store the group averages as a new column using `.transform('mean')`. Then things got complicated. The catch is that what I really want is an average of n-1 values, where 'n' is the number of rows belonging to each group. Example data, where the column **RESULT** is my desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_tuples = [('A', 3, 4.5),
                  ('A', 2, 4.75),
                  ('A', 5, 4),
                  ('A', 4, 4.25),
                  ('A', 7, 3.5),
                  ('B', 6, 6.75),
                  ('B', 9, 6),
                  ('B', 8, 6.25),
                  ('B', 4, 7.25),
                  ('B', 6, 6.75)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=list_of_tuples, columns=['ID', 'VALUE', 'RESULT'])

>>> df
  ID  VALUE  RESULT
0  A      3    4.50
1  A      2    4.75
2  A      5    4.00
3  A      4    4.25
4  A      7    3.50
5  B      6    6.75
6  B      9    6.00
7  B      8    6.25
8  B      4    7.25
9  B      6    6.75
```

You can see that in the first row the value of **RESULT** is the average of [2, 5, 4, 7], which is 4.5. Likewise, the value of **RESULT** for the last row is the average of [6, 9, 8, 4], which is 6.75.

So for each row the value of **RESULT** should be the group average (grouping on **ID**) of **VALUE** *excluding* the number in **VALUE** for that particular row.

Comment: @IanThompson - No. The value of RESULT where index = 3 should exclude VALUE for that row (i.e., 4). The value of results where index = 7 should exclude 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from my comment above.

```
list_of_tuples = [('A', 3, 4.5),
                  ('A', 2, 4.75),
                  ('A', 5, 4),
                  ('A', 4, 4.25),
                  ('A', 7, 3.5),
                  ('B', 6, 6.75),
                  ('B', 9, 6),
                  ('B', 8, 6.25),
                  ('B', 4, 7.25),
                  ('B', 6, 6.75)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples)

df.drop(2, axis = 1, inplace = True)

n = df.groupby(0)[1].transform('count')
m = df.groupby(0)[1].transform('mean')
df['result'] = (m*n - df[1])/(n-1)

df
```

[image: final]